# Error running import javax.swing.JOptionpane

Tags: java, swing

Am relatively new to java programming and I am getting an output error for my code as it relates to the swing aspect

```
import java.io.*;
import Java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class CurrencyConverter
{
public static void main(string[]args)throws IOException
{
String USDollar;
double USD, Euro, Pounds, Rouble;

BufferedReader dataIn=new BufferedReader (newInputStreamReader(System.in));

System.out.println();
System.out.println("\t\t CURRENCY CONVERTER");
System.out.println("\t\t Please enter the Dollar amount in US DOLLAR");
USDollar=dataIn.readLine();
USD=Double.parseDouble(USDollar);

Rouble=(USD*34.89);
Pounds=(USD*0.61);
      Euro=(USD*0.73);

System.out.println();
System.out.println("\t\tYour given amount $"+USD);
System.out.println("\t\tPounds $"+ Pounds);
System.out.println("\t\tRussian Rouble $"+ Rouble);
System.out.println("\t\tEuro $"+Euro);

}
}

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CSwing
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
String USDollar;
double USD,Pounds,Rouble,Euros;

System.out.println("t\tCURRENCY CONVERTER");

USD = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter the Dollar amount in USD");
dUSD=Double.parseDouble(USD);

Rouble=(USD*34.89);
Pounds=(USD*0.61);
Euro=(USD*0.73);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Given Amount: $" +(dUSD)
+"\n\nYour Rouble Conversion is:$"+(Rouble)
+"\n\nYour Pound Conversion is:$"+(Pound)
+"\n\nYour Euro Conversion is:$"+(Euro));
System.exit(0);
}
}
```

the tool output error: `class, interface, enum expected: import javax.swing.JOptionpane`:
I have googled this in an attempt to resolve it myself but I am stuck. I have resolved all the other errors that where present and this is the only one left but why am I having difficulty with this one.  Your assistance with this will truly be appreciated.

Comment: Is all the code you have shown in a single file? If it is then you need to split it into two files (CurrencyConverter.java and CSwing.java).

Comment: this is inserted in the code itself and how do i split the file

Comment: it is all under currencyconverter.java so i have to save the console separate from the swing is that what your indicating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line: `dUSD=Double.parseDouble(USD);` you are attempting to parse a `Double` from `USD` which already is a double.

The `Double.parseDouble(String S)` requires a `String` parameter to be passed into it. Not a `Double`.

Quick fix:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CSwing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String usd;
        double dUSD, pounds, rouble, euros;

        System.out.println("t\tCURRENCY CONVERTER");

        usd  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Please enter the Dollar amount in USD");
        dUSD = Double.parseDouble(usd);

        rouble = (dUSD * 34.89);
        pounds = (dUSD * 0.61);
        euros  = (dUSD * 0.73);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Given Amount: $" + (dUSD)
                + "\n\nYour Rouble Conversion is:$ " + (rouble)
                + "\n\nYour Pound Conversion is:$ "  + (pounds)
                + "\n\nYour Euro Conversion is:$ "   + (euros));
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

As for your `CurrencyConverter`, everything seems fine just some small typographical errors.

Fix:

```
import java.io.*;

public class CurrencyConverter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String usDollar;
        double usd, euro, pounds, rouble;

        BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\t\t CURRENCY CONVERTER");
        System.out.println("\t\t Please enter the Dollar amount in US DOLLAR");
        usDollar = dataIn.readLine();
        usd      = Double.parseDouble(usDollar);

        rouble = (usd * 34.89);
        pounds = (usd * 0.61);
        euro   = (usd * 0.73);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\t\tYour given amount $" + usd);
        System.out.println("\t\tPounds $" + pounds);
        System.out.println("\t\tRussian Rouble $" + rouble);
        System.out.println("\t\tEuro $" + euro);

    }
}
```

Comment: you remove the import java.text.decimalformat was it needed

Comment: As separate files they work properly but how do i get them to work together

Comment: @user3299431 You're gonna have to do some research =D. Buy a book and read it, or google it. All I can say is that you're looking for making an instance of one of your classes to use it in another class. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You have to import everything before all class declarations. So move `import javax.swing.JOptionPane;` up to the top with all of your other declarations. Or like @assylias pointed out just split up the two classes into different files. Oh, and the package `import Java.text.DecimalFormat;` does not exist, make that 'j' in 'Java' lowercase.